# How can I authorize a .NET 5.0 / C# application to interact with Microsoft 365 SharePoint Online without user interaction?

Tags: c#, authentication, sharepoint, integration, csom

I need to create a webservice which will accept a file from a user, parse the file for data, assemble a collection of files stored on Sharepoint, and the return a zip file containing those files to the user.
The user may not have direct access to Sharepoint and in the future there might not even be a human user involved as the file may be pulled automatically from another system on a timer.

I am creating the solution in C# and am struggling to create a client which can successfully authenticate against Sharepoint.

Currently, I am trying to use the [CSOM Authentication Manager](http://ttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard) in the Microsoft documentation, but using the Visual Studio debugger, I observe a failure in this method:

```
        private async Task<string> AcquireTokenAsync(Uri resourceUri, string username, string password)
        {
            string resource = $"{resourceUri.Scheme}://{resourceUri.DnsSafeHost}";

            var clientId = defaultAADAppId;
            var body = $"resource={resource}&client_id={clientId}&grant_type=password&username={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(username)}&password={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password)}";
            using (var stringContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))
            {

                var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, stringContent).ContinueWith((response) =>
                {
                    return response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }).ConfigureAwait(false);

                var tokenResult = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(result);
                var token = tokenResult.GetProperty("access_token").GetString();
                return token;
            }
        }
```

The value of result is:

> "{"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"AADSTS700016: Application with identifier '986002f6-c3f6-43ab-913e-78cca185c392' was not found in the directory 'enpal.de'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.\r\nTrace ID: d3b47a0b-54bc-40fd-a731-b99732326200\r\nCorrelation ID: 158621cc-3052-4c7b-9532-e2bab5c3cc09\r\nTimestamp: 2020-11-18 13:46:39Z","error_codes":[700016],"timestamp":"2020-11-18 13:46:39Z","trace_id":"d3b47a0b-54bc-40fd-a731-b99732326200","correlation_id":"158621cc-3052-4c7b-9532-e2bab5c3cc09","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=700016"}"

The resourceUri, username, and password values correctly correspond to the values I would directly use to log into the website.  My administrator has assured me the user is an admin of the site and therefore should have all the possible permissions it should need to do anything, including connect.

Does anyone know how to make this work?
Or know a different solution which is more likely to work?
Or know of anything which must be configured on the SharePoint side to allow this solution to work?

Comment: It may be that the AAD administrator needs to grant consent to your application in the AAD portal

Comment: @ADyson, my application is still a work in progress in a very early state.  And I have very limited experience with both C# and AAD.  What might we need to do in order to receive this grant?

Comment: I just saw @Vincent's answer below.... so maybe this is the same thing?  Trying now.

Comment: Yes it's broadly the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you took the code sample from the Microsoft website and skipped on reading an important section: [Configuring an application in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard#configuring-an-application-in-azure-ad) ;)

At the moment, you are trying to connect to your tenant as an app with an id of '986002f6-c3f6-43ab-913e-78cca185c392', which is a placeholder from the code sample. Register your app in your tenant, and insert the proper app id in your `defaultAADAppId` constant.

Comment: Yes, you are correct!  I missed this.  Thank you!  I am trying it presently and accept the answer once I verify it works,  :)  (Note: There are a few discrepencies between the documentation and my experience in the UI, but I *think* I've figured out what I need to do....)

Comment: Thanks!  After figuring out which Id it needed and how to grant the permissions, it worked!  :-)